# Schema Include Fails in Unix but Works in Windows

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to build Java classes from a schema. I am using CXF xsdtojava plugin to get it done.

I have configured the plugin just fine and it works on my local system just fine. But I move it to the test environment which is in Unix, it fails to find the import. Can you please tell me if I am doing something wrong in the way the include is done?

Here is the main XSD:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:cms="a_url" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="a_url" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:include schemaLocation="cmsTypes.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="ConfigManSystem">
    <xs:element name="ConfigManSystem">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="cms:dualRouter" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:dualLeaseLine" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:service"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:bVoipService" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:configType" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:configName" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:vendor"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:siteName" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:region"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:countryCode" minOccurs="0"/>               
            <xs:element ref="cms:dataSource" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:nc3OrderNumber" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:equipmentKey" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:credentials" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:device" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:messageList" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:bgpNeighborList" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:aclList" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:bvoip" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="cms:linkedDevices" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And I get the error saying:

```
[INFO] --- cxf-xjc-plugin:3.3.1:xsdtojava (generate-xsd-to-java-jaxb) @ schema-files-jaxb ---
[WARNING] /opt/home/JenkinsHome/workspace/FullBuild/installation/schema-files-jaxb/../config-management-system/src/main/resources/xsdFiles/configManSystemDeviceList.xsd [4:57]: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'cmsTypes.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

The declaration of cmsTypes.xsd is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:cms="a_url" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="a_url" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

If that is of any use.

This works perfectly in Windows 10 machine. But not on Unix.

Comment: Can you please provide your pom.xml too?

Comment: Are configManSystemDeviceList.xsd and cmsTypes.xsd in the same directory?

Comment: @VGR yes they are.

Comment: Is it possible that the first character in cmsTypes.xsd is a [byte order mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/feff/)?  What does the command `hd cmsTypes.xsd | head -n 1` show?

Comment: I got out of office. I will post back on Monday and see what I get.